# Using Win32 API in QT for Windows

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

i'm migrating from .net C# to QT C++, and I'm trying to use this Win32 function to emulate drive in QT:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool DefineDosDevice(int flags, string devname, string path);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int QueryDosDevice(string devname, StringBuilder buffer, int bufSize);
```

The code above is in C# but i'm have no idea how to use them in QT, someone can give me an example how to do this and how to use any Win32 API in QT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for any Answer!
The answer for my question is:

```
#include <Windows.h>

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString qstr1 = "Z:";
    QString qstr2 = getenv("tmp");
    DefineDosDevice(0, (LPCTSTR)qstr1.utf16(), (LPCTSTR)qstr2.utf16());
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QString qstr = "Z:";
    DefineDosDevice(2, (LPCTSTR)qstr.utf16(), 0);
}
```

Comment: You definitely don't need to declare the `DefineDosDevice` function yourself, it's already declared in `Windows.h`. And you *certainly* shouldn't do both.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the documentation for [DefineDosDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363904(v=vs.85).aspx) and [QueryDosDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365461(v=vs.85).aspx), you'll see in the table down the bottom that they are both defined in the "kernel32.lib" library, and declared in "Windows.h" (indirectly).

In your code, you should `#include <Windows.h>`: you'll then be able to make calls to them directly.

I'm not sure about your specific compiler/IDE, but if you get errors at link time about "Unresolved references", you may need to add "kernel32.lib" (from the Windows SDK) to your library path.

Answer (score 2):

add #pragma comment(lib,"user32") in .h or .cpp files

Answer (score 1):

You can use win32 APIs as regular C functions. There is no difference in QT and other C++ programs.